# Rspec command line prompt press enter

Tags: ruby, rspec

I am using rspec to test command line prompt input's result, but seems there are very less topic about testing against it.

Rspec:

```
it "should prompt when no params entered" do
    execute_command("label")
```

Terminal:

```
bundle exec rspec
........................................Volume label (32 characters, ENTER for none)?
```

I therefore need to manually press enter in the command prompt.

How can I do it by some functions like that:

```
execute_command("label")
```

Comment: Have you looked at [IO.popen](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/IO.html#method-c-popen)?

Comment: Yes, but how can i use it the way like: execute_command(:enter) to do so?